How can I get this STDIN to work in GAS Assembler running on Linux?
I am new to Assembler and am currently reading a book about it by Jonathan Bartlett called 'Learn to Program with Assembly'. On pages 160-1 he gives the following sample program to demonstrate the use of the STDIN and STDOUT features of C/C++ in GAS Assembler:
.globl main

.section .data
    promptformat:   .ascii "Enter two numbers separated by spaces, then press RETURN.\n\0"
    scanformat: .ascii "%d %d\0"
    resultformat:   .ascii "The result is %d.\n\0"

.section .text
    .equ    LOCAL_NUMBER, -8
    .equ    LOCAL_EXPONENT, -16
main:
    enter $16, $0

    # PROMPT THE USER FOR INPUT
    movq stdout, %rdi
    movq $promptformat, %rsi
    movq $0, %rax
    call fprintf

    # READ IN DATA
    movq stdin, %rdi
    movq $scanformat, %rsi
    leaq LOCAL_NUMBER(%rbp), %rdx
    leaq LOCAL_EXPONENT(%rbp), %rcx
    movq $0, %rax
    call fscanf

    # PERFORM CALCULATION
    movq LOCAL_NUMBER(%rbp), %rdi
    movq LOCAL_EXPONENT(%rbp), %rsi
    call exponent

    # OUTPUT RESULT FOR USER
    movq stdout, %rdi
    movq $resultformat, %rsi
    movq %rax, %rdx
    movq $0, %rax
    call fprintf

    leave
    ret

When I run the program, the STDOUT giving the prompt works just fine, but when I type in the two integers and hit ENTER, the program does nothing until I am forced to exit with Ctrl-C. It's as though the program is waiting for some type of end-of-line character or something.
(NOTE: This program also calls another program named 'exponent' which is not shown here. If anyone thinks it's necessary, I can post that code, too. Honestly, though, I don't think the exponentscanf program is making it that far anyway.)
I am running Linux Mint-Virginia, and the program is being compiled with GNU: gcc -static exponentscanf.s exponentfunc.s -o exponentscanf.
Here's the code for exponentfunc.s:
.globl exponent
.type exponent, @function

.section .text
exponent:
    enter $16, $0       # 16-byte alignment
    movq $1, %rax       # accumulated value in %rax
    movq %rsi, -8(%rbp) # move quadword value (i.e., the exponent) stored in %rsi to %rbp using an offset of -8
mainloop:
    mulq %rdi       # the base is stored in %rdi
    decq -8(%rbp)       # decrement quadword value stored in %rbp using an offset of -8
    jnz mainloop        # jump if not zero back to the beginning of the loop
complete:
    leave           # result is automatically stored in %rax
    ret


Use GDB to see how far it is getting.  (Single-step with stepi or nexti to step into or over calls when going by single instructions.)  Then make a [mcve] without the call exponent that still has the same problem.  (Or that include the call exponent if it's necessary to repro the problem, and you can't figure it out from using GDB to look at registers before each call.)

Since the code you have showed only prints and does not take input, surely the problem is elsewhere.

@Jester: The 'stdin' is supposed to represent input, just like the 'cin' in C/C++.

In case you are referring to the movq stdin, %rdi that does not do any input it just loads the file pointer (FILE*). You will need call to something like fscanf to actually read input which is probably hidden in exponent. Just like you need fprintf to write output.

Just spotted that movq $scanformat, %rsi and leaq LOCAL_EXPONENT(%rbp), %rsi both write to rsi. I assume the latter should be rcx. As it is, it is overwriting the format string which will presumably break whatever input method you have in exponent.

@Jester: You are correct! I don't know how I missed it, but there's supposed to be an fscanf before the call to exponent. Thank you for pointing that out.

@Jester: Welp, I just added the missing lines to the code for STDIN (see above), but it's still doing the same thing. Where should I look next?

You still have not shown what's in exponent but the code you posted works here.

@Jester: Good point. I am adding the code for 'exponent' to the above right now. Please note that the file in which it is contained is named 'exponentfunc.s'. Is it a problem if the function and the file have different names? (I assumed not, since I am just following Bartlett's lead on this.)

The code as shown works here. Make sure you are running this exact version, that you have recreated the binary properly. Note that %d is a 32 bit format but you use quadwords. Depending on what is in memory you could have a very long loop :)

@Jester: I had no idea. Is there a placeholder specifically for quadwords? Would it be %q maybe?

No, %q does not exist. See man scanf. %ld or %lld

@Jester: Interestingly, it does say the following: "Some combinations of the type modifiers and conversion specifiers defined by ANSI C do not make sense (e.g., %Ld). While they may have a well-defined behavior on Linux, this need not to be so on other architectures. Therefore it usually is better to use modifiers that are not defined by ANSI C at all, that is, use q instead of L in combination with d, i, o, u, x, and X conversions or ll. The usage of q is not the same as on 4.4BSD, as it may be used in float conversions equivalently to L."

@Jester: Welp, I just added an 'l' in front of the 'd' and it seems to work fine now, so that must have been the issue. Thanks for all your patience and help, Jester.
